# Blazor SyncFusion Charts - Click Event

Tags: c#, blazor, syncfusion

SyncFusion Charts for Blazor, `<SfChart>`, is proving great for me, but I cannot figure out how to capture a click on a piece of the chart data, and succesfully establish which item was clicked.

Examples seem absent from the documentation.

I have looked at `OnPointClick` and `OnSelectionComplete`, used with `SelectionMode="SelectionMode.Point"`, to no avail. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague and I have worked out how to parse the required piece of data, in this case a date on the x axis in a `Column` type chart. Here, retrieving the value to a string.

```cs
async public void OnSelection(ISelectionCompleteEventArgs Arguments)
{
    if (Arguments.SelectedDataValues is JArray jArray)
    {
        JToken? token = jArray.FirstOrDefault();

        if (token != null)
        {
            string value = token.Value<string>("x");
        }
    }
}
```